# How could we call a razor page function from a JS file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I am building a Razor pages web application.

I have the following Ajax code which is calling the function "EmpSrc' of file "AddEmp.cshtml". The following Ajax code is in "AddEmp.cshtml". This code is working fine.

I moved this code to a new JS file and added the JS file in "AddEmp.cshtml".

However the code ***url: "@Url.Page(/AddEmp")?handler=EmpSrc",*** is not working in JS file.

**How could we call a razor page function from a JS file?**

```
var searchDataEmp = 'John';
$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Page(/AddEmp")?handler=EmpSrc",
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            dataType: "json",
            data: { searchDataEmp: searchDataEmp }
        }).done(function (result) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked after eliminating ***@Url***.

Used

> ***url: "/AddEmp?handler=EmpSrc",***

in place of

> ***url: "@Url.Page(/AddEmp")?handler=EmpSrc",***

Following is the updated code -

```
var searchDataEmp = 'John';
$.ajax({
            url: "/AddEmp?handler=EmpSrc", 
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            dataType: "json",
            data: { searchDataEmp: searchDataEmp }
        }).done(function (result) {
```